# How to extract surface triangles from a tetrahedral mesh?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, physics, vertices

I want to render a tetrahedral mesh using Blender. However, I cannot directly load the tetrahedral mesh in Blender as the file format that I have for tetrahedral meshes is not supported.

My tetrahedral file format contains vertex IDs for each tetrahedron as follow for a cube:

```
v 0.41 0.41 0.41
v 0.41 0.41 -0.41
v 0.41 -0.41 0.41
v 0.41 -0.41 -0.41
v -0.41 0.41 0.41
v -0.41 0.41 -0.41
v -0.41 -0.41 0.41
v -0.41 -0.41 -0.41
t 0 1 2 4
t 5 1 4 7
t 1 2 4 7
t 3 1 7 2
t 6 4 2 7
```

However, I'm not sure how I can and extract the surface mesh given this data. Does someone know how I can do this?